# simple scan does not appear in startup 14.04

Tags: startup, scanner, startup-applications

I wanted to scan a document. Connected the scanner and then looked for a software on my 14.04 to work it. It seems like I have simple scan of SANE installed, but can't find it. When looking for applications in the startup menu nothing at all appears. When searching for scanner or similar I get references. Think somehing is wrong with the Startup (not sure of the term, my OS is in Spanish and its called inicio). Would appreciate a tip on how to run any application that is not clearly visible, but right now need to find the scanner. Thanks.

Comment: try to open it from terminal by typing `simple-scan` in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `simple` in Dash (top icon in the launcher) and it should show Simple Scan if you have it installed. Click on Simple Scan which should open the utility.

In the launcher on the left of your screen, you should see the Simple Scan Icon (a flat bed scanner). Right click on it and select `Lock to Launcher`.

In future, you can open the utility simply by clicking on the icon in the launcher or by typing `simple-scan`from terminal.

Comment: Thank you. It does work, when the Dash is functioning correctly. My problem is that sometimes the Dash says there is nothing, while I know the program is installed.

Comment: If you find it, as you say, when the dash is functioning correctly, will it not then work consistently when selected from the launcher thereafter?

Comment: It does. However if I don't want it to appear on the launcher (I don't use it that often) I would like to have an alternative or at least understand why the Dash won't do its work properly.

Comment: I've modified my answer to reflect an alternative way of launching the utility from the Terminal. If you're happy with that, perhaps you can mark the answer off.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long